# How to move apply force to bodies in a top down game?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

So I am making a top down game where the player moves using WASD keys. For this I use

```java
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && b2dBody.getLinearVelocity().y >= -0.8) {
    b2dBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, -PLAYER_SPEED), b2dBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
} else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && b2dBody.getLinearVelocity().y <= 0.8) {
    b2dBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0f, PLAYER_SPEED), b2dBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
} else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) && b2dBody.getLinearVelocity().x >= -0.8) {
    b2dBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-PLAYER_SPEED, 0), b2dBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
} else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) && b2dBody.getLinearVelocity().x <= 0.8) {
    b2dBody.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(PLAYER_SPEED, 0), b2dBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
}
```

But because the gravity is set to 0 `world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);` the body doesn't stop. I was wondering if there was a way to keep the gravity the same while making the body stop after after a while? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24417977/libgdx-implementing-moving-kinematic-body

Comment: Some terminology I've learned: in games, a "kinematic" body means something that moves, but is not a physics object.  Examples include a player avatar and a simple moving platform.  So I think you want to be using kinematic bodies, not applying forces to physics bodies.  I'm not an expert in libGDX so take that with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a box2d body you can set the `linearDamping` value of the [BodyDef](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef.html#linearDamping) object that is used to create the body.
This value will always slow down the object when it's moving (e.g. when applying a linear impulse).

You can use it like this:

```
BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
//set other body values
bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.set(42f, 42f);
bodyDef.angle = 0f;
//...
bodyDef.linearDamping = 10f; // this will make the body slow down when moving

//create the body
Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

// TODO move the body arround and it will automatically slow down
```